# why file ownership set on filesystem does not take affect after mount?

Tags: mount

I have rhel 6 plaftform. I added a second disk /dev/sdb and formatted it (ext4 filesystem). Before I mount this partition to a root tree I ran following commands.

```
chown sysadm:sysadm 
chmod 755
mount /foo
```

However when foo is mounted, I ran "ls -l" command under "/" expecting pre-defined ownerhip/permission however /foo is owned by root:root instead of sysadm:sysadm. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

The directory you created is just an empty shell. Despite whatever name you gave it and what ownership, once the new filesystem comes, the only thing that is of interest is the directory name. The new filesystem overlays itself on to this mount point and all the ownership and permissions are whatever was on that new disk is. The old information about the directory, and also if there were any contents in it, are now invisible to the operating system

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. Due to my lack of understanding on Linux, it is a bit hard to digest your explanation although I believe the contents must be something easily understood by experienced linux engineers. I will carefully read again and do research terms/words you laid out. Have a blessed day!

Comment: /foo/bar points to inode 1234 when you  set permissions, you set them on inode 1234, when you mount you point /foo/bar to inode 4567, inode 4567 has different permissions.  ( this illustrates the answer but is technically wrong, just take it with a grain of salt.)